# how to jsonize a custom object with spray?

Tags: json, scala, spray

i'm trying to do the following (i use spray-json_2.9.2 v1.2.3 because i use scala 2.9.2)

```
import spray.json._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

case class TestMe(key: String, value: String)
object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val prot = jsonFormat4(TestMe)
}
```

but i get compilation error:

> TestMe.type (with underlying type object
>   com...TestMe) [INFO]  required: (?, ?, ?, ?) =>
>   ? [INFO]  Note: implicit value prot is not applicable here because it
>   comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
>   [INFO]   implicit val prot = jsonFormat4(TestMe)

what am i doing wrong i just followed docs at: https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-case-classes

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you take a look at all `jsonFormat` signatures you'll that it requires a function, more precisely `apply`:

```
case class TestMe(key: String, value: String)
object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val prot = jsonFormat2(TestMe.apply)
}
```

**AND** jsonFormat is not a macro function, it's just overloaded, so the *number at the end should be equal to the number* of args in case class

In this example your case class has two arguments, so you need `jsonFormat2` and not `jsonFormat4`

And also better rename companion object `MyJsonProtocol` to `TestMe`, this will reduce the explicit import with implicits

Comment: @AlexIv why do we need to extend DefaultJsonProtocol ? it will work fine without that extension:
case class MyJsonProtocol(key: String, value: String)
object MyJsonProtocol {
  implicit val prot = jsonFormat2(MyJsonProtocol.apply)
}

Comment: @igx it works because of `import DefaultJsonProtocol._`, is you take a look this is a companion object which extends this trait. You don't need to extend it in you app, if you have this import. In my answer i just copy pasted the code from the question.